# Correct notation for a matrix subset of an order-3 tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, tensors, index-notation

Consider an order-3 tensor $\mathcal{T} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n\times n}.$ If I want to refer to a matrix "slice" of this tensor, what would be the conventional notation? For instance, in Matlab style (as used by Golub and Van Loan in their *Matrix Computations* text) I might write $\mathcal{T}(:,:,k).$ However I don't believe the journal I am submitting to ever uses this style of notation.